# Timer Closing Forms

Tags: vb.net, timer

I did a lanhouse in vb.net, and when the timer 1 tick (15 minutes) I want the forms to be closed.

```
Dim acabou As Boolean = False
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If acabou = False Then
        acabou = True
        MsgBox("O teu tempo na lan house acabou.")
        Browser.Close()
        sistemaoperativo.Close()
        loginoperativo.Close()
        paint2.Close()
        painti.Close()
        musica.Close()
        calculadora.Close()
        haskear.Close()
        haskear1.Close()
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Stop()
        acabou = False
    End If
   End Sub
```

The forms (browser, sistemaoperativo, etc..) dont close

Comment: Are those types or variables you're referring to in that code?

Comment: Not variables, im referring to the form

Comment: So they are default instances then.  Did you display default instances in the first place?  If not, that would explain why the instances you displayed are not being closed.

Comment: Another important question: Does any of the forms set `e.Cancel` to `True` in their `FormClosing` events? --- Also, `Timer1.Enabled = False` and `Timer1.Stop()` does the **exact** same thing. You only need one of them.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I didn't understand the question, Im new in programming 
@VisualVincent forms I have mentioned don't have `e.Cancel` to `True`

Comment: You're new to programming but you're not new to the web so I assume that you know how to perform a search.  Did you search for the keywords "default instance" in an effort to understand the question?  How EXACTLY did you display these forms in the first place?